# How to override @annotations (javax.validation) in a subClass

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, bean-validation

I have this `Entity`, that is a super class:

```
@Entity
public class Father implements Serializable{    

    @Column(name = "name")
    @Size(min=1, max=10)
    @Pattern(regexp="^[A-Za-z ]*$")
    @NotNull
    private String name;

}
```

this one, extends the one above:

```
@Entity    
public class FatherSub extends Father implements Serializable{  

    private String name;

}
```

As you can see, in `FatherSub` I don't have `@Annotations` and I don't want them.
How can I override them? Is there a way?

It seems that the annotations `@NotNull` persist in the subclass and ask me to fill 
`Father.name` (not `FatherSub.name`) as you can see in these 2 Eclipse printscreen pics.

[image]
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Annotations, which just represent some meta info for some specific period of time, are not over-writable when having a subclass. So it's up to the implementation how annotation inheritance is implemented. For the Validator Framework, annotations scattered over multiple inherited classes are [aggregated](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/7.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-constraint-inheritance).

In your example, the `FatherSub#name` member *hides* the `Father#name` member. This means that all instances of `FatherSub` will work with the `name` defined in `FatherSub`. But because the Validation implementation takes also inherited annotations into account, though the `FatherSub#name` does not have a `@Column` annotation, the error pops up. You can't change this behaviour, so you must choose to either not use inheritance at all or give the child class the validator annotations instead of the parent.

Additionally, you don't need to explicitly implement `Serializable` in `FatherSub`, as `Father` already implements it.

Comment: I am using `@NotNull` annotation on properties in the child class but hibernate adds not null constraint on created tables anyway. I have tried both SINGLE_TABLE and JOINED strategies. Do you know how to solve this issue?